# C# Dynamic WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, dynamic, browser, controls

I have a form, with a webbrowser on it, and what I am doing is cloning the forms, but what needs to happen is that the data from the first webbrowser isn't transfered to the next clone that I make.

This is the code I have.

```
webBrowserForm frm = new webBrowserForm();
frm.Show();
```

Whenever I add a new webbrowser form, the same data from the previous webbrowser is transfered to the new one. I don't know why this is, but it should be pretty easy to fix, right?

By data, I mean the cache and cookies from the previous webbrowser. That is what won't clear when I clone the webbrowser.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately, cookies are shared between all webbrowser instances, they are even shared with IE itself. If you delete the cookies for the new instance, they will be removed for all instances and IE.

Comment: But, If I was to run the actual compiled program twice, I would get the desired effect, because I have tried that, and it works just how I wanted it to.

Comment: As fcuesta stated, the cache and cookies are shared, if you need to to isolate the browsers you may want to look at Awesomium, CefSharp or CefGlue, which are Chrome based browsers that can be embedded in .NET clients, although they are not as drag'n drop.